# Visual Studio 2005: Controls being moved automatically?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-2005

I have been using Visual Studio 2005 for a while now and there have been too many occassions where some of my controls just seem to "move on their own".

The controls I am talking about are buttons situated on a splitcontainer with Anchor Top, Right. (Perhaps the anchor has something to do with it?)

How it should be:

http://img16.imageshack.us/i/afterv.png/

How it was this morning when I opened my project (this has happened more than once by now), note that the buttons are no longer situated as close to the right border as in the previous picture:

http://img195.imageshack.us/i/beforelm.png/

This is mildly frustrating as I have no idea how to Google this, it will probably be the result of my own doings. If I have missed any information you require, please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is an option in Format menu to lock the controls once they are aligned properly, have you used that ??

Comment: @Furqan: I have tried that before. The thing is, I can't remember whether I ever had this problem when I locked the controls. I will make sure it is locked everytime I close my project to see if this problem occurs even after that. As good as this is, I am still curious what is going wrong. If it is because I drag the buttons too close to the border or something else I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Anchor them propely and fix the size of the form to a minimum size so that all controls are in proper place.

Comment: What is wrong with the Top, Right anchoring then? Also, could you be more specific what you mean with "fix the size of the form to a minimum ...".

Comment: Arrange all the controls in proper position and fix the form's minimum size to the size in which all controls are proper. Finally set the anchors.

Comment: Alright, I've set the minimum size of my form to the size it is in Designer mode. I will have to test how much problems this will give, it's an embedded C# User Control in Centura (using COM).